# Error loading dojo file locally: "Loading failed for the <script> with source ..."

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, offline

I'm attempting to add ArcGIS maps to a website that's on a restricted network (and therefore needs to work offline). I've been trying to get the ArcGIS ESRI maps running offline, but I'm not sure how it's supposed to be implemented. I added the `arcgis_api_js` folder to the root folder of my Visual Studio project (following the "AMD files hosted locally" instructions here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/install-and-set-up/), but when I try to reference the file mentioned, I get the error `Loading failed for the <script> with source "http://localhost:57698/arcgis_js_api/library/4.18/dojo"`.

In my `init.js` and `dojo.js` files (referenced on the web page using the map) I set the `baseURL` to the address above with the intention of changing it to the IIS address used by our restricted network when live.

Is there something I missed or is it not possible to run the maps locally without hosting the api library on a server at the same time?

For reference my .aspx page has this reference to the dojo file:

```
<script src="../arcgis_js_api/library/4.18/dojo/dojo.js">
</script>
```

And the `dojo.js` and `init.js` have this code replacing the boilerplate `baseURL`:

```
{async:1,baseUrl:"http://localhost:57698/arcgis_js_api/library/4.18/dojo",hasCache:{"config-selectorEngine":"lite","config-tlmSiblingOfDojo":1,"dojo-built":1,"dojo-loader":1,dom:1,"host-browser":1}
```